# How to convert a Decimal number to Binary number using divide and conquer technique?

Tags: divide-and-conquer

I am stuck with a question which says to apply `divide` and `conquer` to convert a `decimal number` to `binary`.

I have written this simple code for conversion but don't know how can I apply `divide` and `conquer` here.

```
def d2b(n):
   b = []
   while n > 0:
       r = n%2
       n //= 2
       b.insert(0,r)
   return b
```

Any idea or hint would be a great help. I want to construct a function which uses a `divide and conquer` method.

Answer (score 1):

```html
Try it.

C# program to convert a decimal 
 number to binary number 
 
 
using System;
public class Dese 
{ 
 
 // function to convert decimal 
 // to binary 
 static void decToBinary(int n) 
 { 
  // array to store binary number 
  int[] binaryNum = new int[1000]; 

  // counter for binary array 
  int i = 0; 
  while (n > 0) 
  { 
   // storing remainder in 
   // binary array 
   binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
   n = n / 2; 
   i++; 
  } 

  // printing binary array 
  // in reverse order 
  for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
   Console.Write(binaryNum[j]); 
 } 
 
 // Driver Code 
 public static void Main () 
 { 
  int n = 17; 
  decToBinary(n); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Pankaj. But I have to construct a function which uses divide and conquer methodology. Do have any idea?